# Build tools for front end code

Tags: angularjs, html, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to know, if there is any build tool for client side code like angularjs,html5 and other techs.
Like we are using Jenkins for server side code to trigger build.
Since these build tools notify us of failing and passing similarly I need for frontend code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). This is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Billy!! I am using Grunt. I will explain you more, if my code is getting saved to a server then it should be paasing a certain build, for which is there any tool?

Comment: It should be passing the build for DEPLOYING code on server